# Django ModelForm with User data in Generic View

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a model with a foreign key to group (the other fields don't matter):

```
class Project(models.Model) :
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    ...
```

I have a model form for this model:

```
class AddProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Project
    fields = ["group","another"]
```

In my urls, I am using this in a generic view:

```
(r'^$', create_object, {'form_class':AddProjectForm, 'template_name':"form.html", 'login_required':True, 'extra_context':{'title':'Add a Project'}}),
```

That all works, but I want to have the group field display only the groups that the current user belongs to, not all of the groups available. I'd normally do this by passing in the user to the model form and overriding init if I wasn't in a generic view. Is there any way to do this with the generic view or do I need to go with a regular view to pass in that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is gonna look dirty, since the generic view instantiates the form_class with no parameters. If you **really** want to use the generic_view you're gonna have to generate the class dynamically :S

```
def FormForUser(user):
  class TmpClass(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(TmpClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['group'].queryset = user.group_set.all()

    class Meta:
      model = Project
      fields = ['group', 'another']
```

Then wrap the create object view

```
@login_required # Only logged users right?
def create_project(request):
  user = request.user
  form_class = FormForUser(user)
  return create_object(request, form_class=form_class, ..... )
```

My recommendation is to write your own view, it will give you more control on the long term and it's a trivial view.

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll need to make a regular view. As can be seen by looking at the source code for create_object(), there's no functionality to pass in extra parameters to the modelform (in django 1.2):

http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/branches/releases/1.2.X/django/views/generic/create_update.py